# mongoose query except array items

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The problem is that I have an array which maybe like [1,2,3], and the content is video._id I don't want to get.

```
var used = [1, 2 , 3];
Video.findOne({'videoClass': watchRecord[i]}).ne('_id', used).sort('-viewTimes').exec(function (err, doc) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            temp.push(doc);

            }
        });
```

I find ne or {$ne:}, but it's not work. How to query data that except items in array I don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ne` operator is not supposed to be used with an Array, I think you need to use `$nin`.

Related links:

- [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-nin)
- [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)